# How do I get Google Calendar to return specific items with recurrence rules?

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I have the following setup:

1. My school computer lab has a publicly accessible Google Calendar giving the schedule and stating whether the lab is open, closed, or blue (need blue (full-period) pass to enter).
2. I would like to make a page that uses the Google Calendar API to pull the events used to mark these, so to make it easier on me and my fellow students to check without the possibility of Google's widget breaking down.
3. When I ask the Google API for the events from the calendar, it gives me twice as many events as there are in a day, with me having no way to know which events are currently active.

For example, consider the following "schedule" (I'm not giving people the link, since it would reveal where I live and go to school):

```
BLUE Per. 1
OPEN Per. 2
BLUE Per. 3
OPEN Per. 4
BLUE Per. 5a
BLUE Per. 5b
CLOSED Per. 6a
OPEN Per. 6b
OPEN Per. 6c
CLOSED Per. 7
OPEN Per. 8
OPEN 9th Per.
```

Currently, when I ask Google for what events are today on the calendar:

```py
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
calendar = build("calendar","v3",developerKey="AaaaaNICE-TRYaaaa01345")
events = calendar.events().list(calendarId="CALENDARID@calendar.google.com",timeMin="2019-12-16T00:00:00-05:00",timeMax="2019-12-16T23:59:59-05:00")
count = len(events["items"]) # 24 (note there were only 12 earlier)
print([item["summary"] for item in events["item"]]) # ['OPEN Per. 7', 'OPEN Per. 5a', 'OPEN Per. 5b', 'OPEN Per. 4', 'OPEN Per. 2', 'OPEN Per. 6b', 'OPEN Per. 6c', 'Open 9th Per.', 'Open Per. 3', 'BLUE Per. 1', 'BLUE Per. 8', 'OPEN Per. 6a', 'BLUE Per. 3', 'BLUE Per. 5a', 'BLUE Per. 5b', 'OPEN Per. 8', 'CLOSED Per. 7', 'OPEN 9th Per.', 'OPEN Per. 6c', 'OPEN Per. 6b', 'BLUE Per. 1', 'OPEN Per. 4', 'OPEN Per. 2', 'CLOSED Per. 6a']
```

[This is the items JSON](https://ttm.sh/E2v.txt) (sanitized for anonymity)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo I need to be able to narrow the 24 items I have in my API response to the 12 that are actually on the calendar.

Comment: You say that there are twice as many events showing up as are viewable in the calendar? Of the 24 responses, only 6 event names show up twice (Open Per 4, Open Per 2, Open per 6b, Open Per 6c, Open 9th Per and Blue Per 1) and the others all only show up once. These events all appear to be different, is it possible some where deleted and have not been propagated fully? Or added to the calendar by another person, perhaps?

Comment: Some of them seem to have "UNTIL"s in their RRULEs... let me try removing those

Comment: Did this solve your issue?

Comment: Yes, that seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the calendar events had `UNTIL`s in their RRULEs. After removing those events and sorting by period, it matched the events on the calendar.